# Does Ctrl2Cap work with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, ctrl

The old Unix environments, X-windows, and power text editors make extensive use of the Ctrl key.  When running such environments & apps on modern era Windows laptops, e.g., perhaps via Cygwin, the odd placement of Ctrl keys are a handicap, and can easily lead to carpal tunnel syndrome.

One solution in the past few decades has been Sysinternals's [Ctr2Cap](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/ctrl2cap), which seems to have been taken over by Microsoft (assuming that it didn't originate from a Microsoft effort).

Does anyone know whether Ctrl2Cap works on Windows 10?

Comment: "Client: Windows Vista and higher." So it should work.

Comment: Doh.  Didn't read carefully enough.  That's assuring.  Would someone using Windows 10 be able to confirm?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it broke keyboard input, and I had to restore using System Restore. When I have more time I can research, but *make sure* you have System Restore ready and available.

Comment: Good to know, mjgoins.  I've disciplined myself to use the prevailing keyboard layout.  It's a pain, but not nearly as great a pain as becoming dependent on ye olde unix positioning of Ctrl and then being helpless when away from that environment.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that it works on Windows 10. I unzipped the archive, ran `.\ctrl2cap.exe /install` in the directory and restarted my computer; now my caps lock key and both my ctrl keys behave like ctrl.

Comment: Thanks, IFcoltransG!  So far, I've avoided doing this.  I think I'd fare better in this world of Caps Lock keys if I get use to doing old Unixy and Vim-like things with the prevailing keyboard layout.  When I get too dependent on a better positioning of Ctrl, such as with Ctrl2Cap, it's a sobering experience using any other computer than my own.  Many times, however, I was tempted to fall off the wagon and install Ctrl2Cap, but not yet.

Answer (score 1):

For a several Win10 installations I successfully use following patch that should be applied to registry (for example create text file named caps_to_control.reg):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```